# jQuery hamburger menu - multiple events called

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue

```
$( document ).on( "vclick", '#icon', function() {

    $("#navigation").animate({height: 'toggle'}, 600, "linear");

});
```

Hello,

I currently have a hamburger menu that works perfectly except for one thing. If I click the `#icon` 10 times, it will execute the code 10 times, I wonder if its possible to make it only clickable when its finished and remove the whole queue system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could set a variable indicating that it's been called already. Then check for it first when the function is called.

Comment: Yes, exactly as the post below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do something in the lines of this:

JavaScript

```
var animating = false;
$(document).on( "vclick", '#icon', function() {
   if(!animating) {
      animating = true;
      $("#navigation").animate({height: 'toggle'}, 600, "linear", function() {
         animating = false;
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you man. I will approve this message in short, works excellent :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Arg0n's answer as inspiration, I have created a jQuery plugin.

The plugin used closure which means that the function returns another function so that variables are scoped inside, rather than outside; in the global scope.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.collapser = function(targetSelector, ms, type) {
    this.on('click', function() {
      var animating = false;
      return (function() {
        if (!animating) {
          animating = true;
          $(targetSelector).animate({
            height: 'toggle'
          }, ms, type, function() {
            animating = false;
          });
        }
      }());
    });
  }
}(jQuery))

$('#icon').collapser('#navigation', 600, 'linear');
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

#page {
  background: #DDD;  
}

#icon {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  line-height: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background: #446;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: thin solid #AAD;
}

ul#navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background: #E7E7F7;
}

ul#navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6em;
  height: 2.5em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #F7F7FF;
}

#content {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 1em;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="page">
  <div id="icon">Icon</div>
  <ul id="navigation">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Articles</li>
    <li>Historic</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="content">
    Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You could also unbind and re-bind the event. This way you don't have to create any state variables. This may be the best way to handle this.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.collapser = function(targetSelector, ms, type) {
    var eventName = 'click';
    var fn = function(source) {
      $(source).unbind(eventName, fn);
      $(targetSelector).animate({
        height: 'toggle'
      }, ms, type, function() {
        $(source).bind(eventName, fn);
      });
    };
    this.on(eventName, function() {
      fn.call(this);
    });
  }
}(jQuery))

$('#icon').collapser('#navigation', 1600, 'linear');
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

#page {
  background: #DDD;  
}

#icon {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  line-height: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background: #446;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: thin solid #AAD;
}

ul#navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background: #E7E7F7;
}

ul#navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6em;
  height: 2.5em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #F7F7FF;
}

#content {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 1em;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="page">
  <div id="icon">Icon</div>
  <ul id="navigation">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Articles</li>
    <li>Historic</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="content">
    Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want it to be executed once, I want it to be executed multiply times but not in a queue order :) thanks for your input though.

Comment: Actually it was a good code, could be used for multiply functions instead of having too much code. Thanks mate :)!

Comment: @J.Doe I added a way to unbind and re-bind the event.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a workaround by hidding the `#icon` until the animation done then show it again :

```
$( document ).on( "vclick", '#icon', function() {
    var _this = $(this);

    //Hide the icon
    $(this).hide();

    $("#navigation").animate({height: 'toggle'}, 600, "linear", function() {
          //Show the icon after animation
          _this.show();
    });

});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This also works excellent except that it removes the button which was not my intention, but regardless I appreciate your input and thank you for your time :)

Comment: You're welcome, it could be just disabled instead of hide.. :) anyway happy coding